# Shiny DT appearance messed up when selected rows used as reactive values

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, reactive-programming

The tables displayed through the DataTables interface from DT package appear messy (e.g. disordered elements, strange looking pagination ...) when using reactive values which their input come from the rows selected in the first table. Using R version `3.4.3`, and shiny `1.1.0` and DT `0.4` which both are sourced from CRAN.

[image]

The minimal code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("dt"),
  actionButton("go", "Go"),
  wellPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("selected"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dt <-  DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      mtcars,
      style = 'bootstrap',
      filter = 'top',
      rownames = FALSE,
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      selection = list(mode = 'single'),
      options = list(
        pageLength = 10,
        dom = '<"top"ifl>t<"bottom"Bp>',
        buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel'),
        searchHighlight = TRUE
      )
    )
  })

  rv <- reactiveValues(val = FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    rv$val <- input$go
  })
  observeEvent(input$dt_rows_selected, {
    rv$val <- FALSE
  })

  output$selected <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if (rv$val == FALSE)
      return()

    reactive({
      validate(need(input$dt_rows_selected != "", "Select a row."))
      mtcars[input$dt_rows_selected, ]
    }) -> .mtcars

    isolate({
      DT::datatable(
        .mtcars(),
        style = 'bootstrap',
        filter = 'top',
        rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = 'Buttons',
        selection = list(mode = 'single'),
        options = list(
          pageLength = 10,
          dom = '<"top"ifl>t<"bottom"Bp>',
          buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel'),
          searchHighlight = TRUE
        )
      ) -> table
    })
    table
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It looks decent without the second table:

[image]

Comment: When you note that "It looks decent without the second table:" what have you changed from the code? As in are the values in the first table still reactive?

Comment: Yes, I should have noted that. I only kept the first table (`dt`) in both server and ui. And the values in the first table aren't reactive.

Comment: Does adding second table without reactive values, just to test, look normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the part `style = 'bootstrap'` which does not work well with `return(NULL)`. Replacing `if (rv$val == FALSE) return()` with `req(rv$val)` in the output has solved the problem. Has taken the reference [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/517).